# ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, pip, scipy, python-wheel

I wanted to use cv2 in my code so I used

```
import cv2
```

But it gave me error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

So, I tried using

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel #successfully upgraded
pip install opencv-python
```

But it also gave me error:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Then I tried

```
 pip3 install git+https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python
```

but it still gives me an error.

Please help me to install openCV so that I may use import cv2.

#### SOLUTION

I could solve the issues using

```
pip install opencv-python==4.3.0.36
```

Comment: Hi @A. Gehani. Two things: 1. If you have a solution, even imperfect, add it as an answer so that people can see it (comments get removed). 2. Do you have more lines above and under the error "ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python" that could tell why the building of wheels failed? It could be helpful to add them in your question!